# How the Scheduler decides about the time for the time-quantum in RoundRobin Scheduling Algorithm?

Tags: operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, scheduler, job-scheduling

In round robin scheduling algorithms , the scheduling is done based upon the time quantum for a particular program. how will the scheduler decide/sets the time quantum for the particular set of processes in advance?

Also which job scheduling algorithm is optimal?

Comment: Scheduling algorithms are OS dependent.  Unless running games, desktop systems usually have enough cores/CPU free to mostly avoid any kind of time-shared CPU scheduling, RR or otherwise.

Comment: @MartinJames I know the Scheduling Algorithms are OS dependent but lets say there are limited cores and Scheduling does occur on time sharing basis then how the time quantum will be set.